# what is Scope chain augmentation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand the Scope chain augmentation of javascript.
i found an example,

```
function buildUrl(){
    var qs = "?debug=true";
    with(location){
    var url = href +qs;
}
    return url;
}
```

anyone can provide any easy example, that will be more helpfull for me :)
Thanks :) :)

Comment: A variable declared with `var` inside the `with`-block is added to its surrounding scope (`buildUrl`). `with` acts similar to the global `window` object, except in this respect. Btw, `with` is deprecated in Javascript. Look into this [blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/with-statement.html)

Answer (score 1):

To start with, in JavaScript `var` is scoped to the function that it appears in, **not** the block that it is in. So if there is a block in the function (like an if statement) any `var` defined inside the if statement will be scoped to the function:

```js
function foo() {
  if (1 === 1) {
    var output = "Something";
  }
  console.log(output);
}

foo();
```

When you are inside a `with` block, you specify a "context" to work with. So in your case you are working with the location. When you reference a variable, it will first look for the variable in the context of `location`, if it can't find it, it will look at the function scope:

```js
function foo() {
  var notInLocation = "something "; // Not as attribute of location
  var pathname = "something else"; // Is as attribute of location
  // the pathname in the location here seems to be "/js"
  
  with (location) {
    console.log(notInLocation + href); // href is a attribute of location and notInLocation isn't
    console.log(pathname + href); // hred and pathname are both attributes in location
  }
}

foo()
```

So in your `with` block, it will first try `location.qs` and will not find an attribute with the name `qs`, so it will look at the function scope and pick up the variable that you defined earlier.